# Creating objects in javascript as functions - and control them with arrow keys in game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to make a simple "game" in HTML5 (mainly Javascript), where you simply move a ball around.

I would like to create a ball (which can be moved with arrow keys) by drawing a circle on canvas. Is this possible, or is another approach simpler?

I would like to create it as a function, so that I have a means for selecting the ball.
Anyways, I am able to draw a triangle, but not a circle. This is the code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = canvas.height = 500;

function circle() {
    // the circle - DOESNT SHOW UP
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(50, 50, 25, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fill();
}

cicle();


function drawTriangle() {
  // the triangle - works perfectly
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(200, 100);
  ctx.lineTo(170, 150);
  ctx.lineTo(230, 150);
  ctx.closePath();
 
  // the fill color
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 204, 0, 1)";
  ctx.fill();
}

drawTriangle();
```

Can anyone figure, why the circle doesn't appear?
IMPORTANT: The circle appears perfectly, when it is NOT part of a function

P.S.: Im very new to web development etc. 
Thanks for any advice

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow thesystem! Have you [checked your console?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log) You appear to have a typo and your console will tell you what it is.

Comment: Thank you very much, both for help and advice. I do have a console (using Visual Studio Code), but for some reason it didn't show up there. Will use chrome debugger from now, since my program missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that that is due to the typo when you call the circle function? So `circle()` instead of `cicle()`

Comment: You are completely right, major mistake on my part. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is quite simple. When you call a function in javascript, you must spell it the same as in the function declaration otherwise you will be calling a function that does not exist.

```
function circle(){
  //code to draw circle
}

//then when i want to call circle function i do this
circle();
//this calls non-existant "cicle" function
cicle();
```

So, there is nothing wrong with your function, just how you called it.